# Why can't I compile the Boost.Serialization demo?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, g++

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to get Boost.Serialization set up, and I'm running into trouble compiling the first demo from the [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) (titled A Very Simple Case). I have followed the Boost [Getting Started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) page for installing Boost and building Serialization, doing the following:

- download the code from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/) (I have tried different versions including 1.67.0 and 1.55.0)
- `cd boost_1_55_0`
- `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local --with-libraries=serialization`
- `sudo ./b2 install`
- check that `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` include the relevant Boost files

and then I compile `demo.cpp` using

`g++ -o demo demo.cpp -I /usr/local/include/boost -l boost_serialization`

and get the following error:

> /tmp/cc9a7HRg.o: In function `boost::archive::text_iarchive::text_iarchive(std::istream&, unsigned int)':
>   demo.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveC2ERSij[_ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveC5ERSij]+0x36): undefined reference to`boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::shared_ptr_helper()'
>   /tmp/cc9a7HRg.o: In function `boost::archive::text_iarchive::~text_iarchive()':
>   demo.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveD2Ev[_ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to`boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::~shared_ptr_helper()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The line causing the error is

```
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
```

It is worth mentioning that the output line

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
```

was causing a similar error before the most recent re-install. Also, if I comment out all of the input (including the line causing the error), the program compiles fine, but causes a segmentation fault upon running. I have included `cout << "done" << endl;` at the end of `main`, but it is not reached.

Does anybody know what might be causing this error? Sorry if this seems like a silly question. I am very new to C++ development. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i'm not a linux developer but I notice you have `boost` in your -I path. The -I should point to the boost root directory. and the includes should be `<boost/some.hpp>`

Comment: Out on a limb I suspect that the binaries are not matching the version of the headers or have been built with different compiler flags/versions

Comment: Thank you guys for you responses. I have managed to fix the issue. I will update with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

worked for me.

This command is taken from the same source as lboyd's solution:
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/getting-started-with-the-boost-libraries-in-ubuntu-linux/

then I compile with

```
g++ serialization.cpp -lboost_serialization -lboost_system
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else running into this issue, I managed to fix it by manually uninstalling everything I had installed from source (deleting the relevant Boost files from `/usr/locale/include/` and `/usr/local/lib/` as well as the root Boost directory) and installing using `apt-get` as described [here](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/getting-started-with-the-boost-libraries-in-ubuntu-linux/).